# How should I remove closed cell spray foam insulation which has shifted the framing?

Tags: insulation

We had our basement spray foamed last week and when the foam expanded it pushed out a 2foot section abound an inch from the block wall is there an easy way to remove part of that foam and push the wall back or would I be better off just trimming the board back so I can put up my sheetrock?[image]

Comment: My first attempt would be with a 6 lb. sledge and a "beater block" (to protect the framing). You might just be able to crush the foam behind the framing enough to reposition it and not tear up the rest of the insulation. You'll have to bash on the studs, too, and the plate for at least 4 feet. Once you do, secure the plate.

Comment: When you're all done, lay a long (6 ft. plus) straightedge on the wall at various points to look for bulges and dips. Better to discover problems now than after the drywall is up.

Answer (score 1):

That's the problem with splitting a plate but not under a stud. There should be a stud where your plate is cut. You have 2 options...

1. Dig out the insulation, lower 8 - 12 " or so, and drive the plate back in place then secure it to your slab.
2. Trim the plate as you've suggested. However, that's not really straight forward as your framing is now out of whack. Check to see if the stud to the right of the split in the plate is still plumb. It may need a "shave" too.

Comment: It's going to take more than a foot up. The stud is pushed out over its entire height.  The entire bottom half will need to be excavated or crushed in, and there'll still be a slight bulge.